# How can I change all keys in certain way in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

So I have this dictionary:

```
sample = {"accessNumber":"0000093410-20-000010", "symbol": "CVX", "cik": "93410"}
```

I would like to take the keys of the dictionary and append the string "late_" to the beginning of every key.

so the dictionary will become like this:

```
sample = {"late_accessNumber":"0000093410-20-000010", "late_symbol": "CVX", "late_cik": "93410"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need that for? The logic is straight forward. Why don't you modify the code accessing the dict instead of the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
sample = {"accessNumber":"0000093410-20-000010", "symbol": "CVX", "cik": "93410"}

new_sample = {'late_'+key: value for key,value in sample.items()}
print(new_sample)
```

Output:

```
{'late_accessNumber': '0000093410-20-000010', 'late_symbol': 'CVX', 'late_cik': '93410'}
```